# How to convert time.gmtime()-like tuple to UNIX time?

Tags: python, time, localtime

`time.mktime` is said to be the reverse of time.localtime.

Where is the reverse of time.gmtime? It is needed to convert the result of email.utils.parsedate to normal UNIX time.

The only approximation is hack like this:

```
time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate(smth)) - time.altzone
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [`calendar.timegm(tuple)`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm)

Comment: Always seemed stupid to me that that function was in a completely separate module, rather than the time module.